# Can a voltage drop happen at a node in parallel circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

In this [Making Logic Gates from Transistors video](https://youtu.be/sTu3LwpF6XI) by Ben Eater, he says the voltage drop will occur at a node in a parallel circuit. But in my knowledge, in parallel circuits, voltage remains the same in branch points; it's rather the current that's separated due to charge conservation.

For clarity I will write down what he says with a screencap.

[[Same video but time stamped]](https://youtu.be/sTu3LwpF6XI?t=173)

> But if we turn the transistor on, that will [sort of] allow the
> current to flow through the transistor here, and **that will lower the
> voltage potential at this node.**

The node is the top red circle in the circuit diagram below

[image]

What I think is this:

The internal resistance of the transistor is very low, so there's minimal voltage drop across the transistor. Plus he just made a mistake in his narration, and he meant the current is lowered, which agrees with the fact that more current flows through the branch with less resistance in a parallel circuit, i.e., the transistor in this case. Thus, there would be not enough current - power - to light the LED up.

But I'm not too sure. What is actually going on?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I wouldn't object to migration.

Answer (score 0):

> But if we turn the transistor on, that will [sort of] allow the
> current to flow through the transistor here, and that will lower the
> voltage potential at this node.

This is a correct statement in that the [node voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) in question *does* decrease when the transistor is on. Consider:  put the black lead of your voltmeter at the emitter of the transistor (the circuit common node or 'ground'), and put your red lead on the node that is the junction of the transistor collector, LED anode, and the lower lead of the right-most resistor. The voltage read by the voltmeter will be lower when the transistor is on than when it is off.

Note that the anode of the LED, the collector of the transistor, and the lower end of the right-most resistor are (ideally) the *same circuit node*. You could (conceptually) reduce the length of the connecting wires to zero.